# Uploading a blob from a client java application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I currently have the following problem:

I would like to upload a `Blob` to the Google Blobstore from my client Java application. In the Blobstore documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) is described how to do this with a form with which the `Blob` is uploaded by using a `FileChooser`.

However, I would like to do this from my code, but I do not know how to convert the `Object` to a `Blob` in Java. I would like to pass the generated `Blob` in a `HttpURLConnection`, and I have created the classes for this on the Google App Engine.

**So my question is: how can I upload a `Blob` from a client java application?**

Note: in my case I would like to upload a `JavaFX` `Image` as a `Blob`, but I think this question could be asked in general.

**UPDATE 1:** Using the `FileService` could be the solution, as @TejjD kindly pointed out. However, the Files API is going to be deprecated and is therefore not useful.

**UPDATE 2:** I am using the following code on the server:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Check if there is a parameter for the outfit id
     try {
        if (!req.getParameter("id").isEmpty() && Functions.isInteger(req.getParameter("id"))) {

            //Check if the requested id exists in the Cloud SQL database
            Connection conn = ConnectionManager.connectToCloudSQL();
            GetQueryBuilder query = DataManager.executeGet(conn, req, "outfit");

            //Check result
            if (query.getResultSet() == null) {
                throw new Exception("The Outfit object with the requested ID is not yet present in the Cloud SQL database");
            }

            Map<String,List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
            BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("image").get(0);

            if (blobKey == null) {
                throw new Exception("No blobkey specified");
            } 
            else {

               //First create a checksum from the file
               String checkSum = this.buildCheckSum(blobKey);

               PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

               //Create new outfit object
               int outfitId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
               OutfitExtension outfit = new OutfitExtension();
               outfit.setId(outfitId);
               outfit.setImage(blobKey);
               outfit.setCheckSum(checkSum);

               pm.makePersistent(outfit);

            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("An outfit ID needs to be added to the HTTP request and should be from type Integer only.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Bad request: "+e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

This code is run when some URL is called (I have connected this in the `web.xml`).
As you can see in the code, it is about `blobstoreService.getUploads(req)`. How can I post `Blob` directly in which it is recognized as a upload?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However, I have linked to that information myself. What extra info does it give me about this question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, I would advise you to perhaps have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754476/upload-an-image-to-google-app-engine-blobstore-with-java-programmatically)

However, I am inserting a code snippet that might answer your question in terms of you wanting to upload via code.

---

```js
public static BlobKey toBlobstore(Blob imageData) throws FileNotFoundException, FinalizationException, LockException, IOException {
    if (null == imageData)
        return null;

    // Get a file service
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();

    // Create a new Blob file with mime-type "image/png"
    AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("image/jpeg");// png

    // Open a channel to write to it
    boolean lock = true;
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);

    // This time we write to the channel directly
    writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap
        (imageData.getBytes()));

    // Now finalize
    writeChannel.closeFinally();
    return fileService.getBlobKey(file);
}
```

---

UPDATE: (For POST method):

```js
// file Upload.java

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;

public class Upload extends HttpServlet {
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("myFile");

        if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
            res.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

That is what you can use to parse the image and upload it.

I hope this assists you :)

All the best!

Let me know of the outcome.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TejjD, appreciate it! However, where can I specify the URL to which the write needs to be done? Also, the `FileService` is deprecated, so I am not keen on using that.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could shed some light. Where do you wish for it to be written to?

Comment: I would like to write it to the `Blobstore` using a POST url connection, see my updated question.

Comment: Alright I see what you mean. I have updated my answer, I am working on incorporating what the api, on the link you have already provided, says. I will get back to you on a solution as soon as possible :), I just had a look at your "Update 2" I will use that in finding a solution for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for not using Google Cloud storage instead of blobstore?
See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries for information about the GCS standard library or https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client for a more convenient access from App Engine.